# What is the center of $V$, the Klein 4 group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Please help - in my notes, it is the group $V$ itself. I just want to confirm this. Can you also explain and give an example if that is possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every abelian group is its own center.  If you look at the definitions you will see this.

Answer (score 5):

You know, this group has only 4 elements. You could just multiply them out. Really, there are only three worthwhile elements, as one is an identity and that commutes with everything.

It would take less than 5 minutes, and you could do it Cayley style or full-on multiplication table style. It would probably even be good for you, as you might get a feel for what groups really are.

Comment: You're answering to a thread more than a year old. I hope OP has figured it out by now :)

Comment: Besides - Cayley graphs don't make you feel what groups really are.

Comment: @t.b. Oh... Zev edited the question 14 hours ago, and I never pay attention to original post dates. So I thought I was answering an hour-old thread. Whoops.

Comment: @Martin: I never said cayley graphs would make him get a good feel, I said carrying out the multiplication would. I think this problem demonstrated a lack of understanding of group computation, that's all.